# Theorem text rendered after figure instead of before

Tags: floats, theorems

I'm trying to place a figure inside a theorem. However, in the following example, the "test" text is rendered under the figure, and not above as it should be. What can I do to fix that?
Minimum working example  :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newtheorem{exercice}{Exercice}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercice}
Test
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{F2.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{exercice}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\begin{figure}[h]\centering`

Comment: if there is enough room on the page for the graphic, don't set it as a float.  take a look at this question: [Force figure placement in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625/579)

Comment: It works, but I'm actually trying to display 2 figures containing 2 minipages each, meaking a 2x2 rectangle of minipages, and the \centering make the 4 minipages display vertically, and if I remove it, the theorem text appears after the figures again

Comment: There's no need of a `figure` environment for using `\includegraphics`, no matter how many of them you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply removed the `figure` environment, since it wasn't necessary.
Here's the working code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newtheorem{exercice}{Exercice}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercice}
Test
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{F2.pdf}
\end{exercice}
\end{document}
```